# Run spark python job with Oozie and Hue - Intercepting System.exit(1)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, oozie, hue, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have to run some Spark python scripts as Oozie workflows, I've tested the scripts locally with Spark but when I submit them to Oozie I can't figure out why is not working. 
I'm using the Cloudera VM, and I'm managing Oozie with the Hue dashboard. Here is the workflow configuration for the spark action:

```
Spark Master: local[*]
Mode: client
App name: myApp
Jars/py files: hdfs://localhost:8120/user/cloudera/example.py
Main class: org.apache.spark
```

I tried also to run a simple example that just prints something, but every script I submit Oozie gives me this output:

```
>>> Invoking Spark class now >>>

Intercepting System.exit(1)

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exit code [1]

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully

Oozie Launcher, uploading action data to HDFS sequence file: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/oozie-oozi/0000005-161228161942928-oozie-oozi-W/spark-cc87--spark/action-data.seq

Oozie Launcher ends
```

[EDIT]

I found out that the workflow starts only if I set spark master: yarn-cluster, but even in this mode it is launched the yarn container that remains stuck at 95% completed map while spark app remains in status ACCEPTED. I'm trying to change Yarn memory parameters for allowing the Spark action to start. The stout just print Heartbeat

[SOLVED]

The oozie workflow starts only if the py file is local, and manually inserted into the lib folder after hue has created the workflow folder. I think that the best solution is still to write a shell script with a spark-submit

Comment: is your python hdfs location correct ? `hdfs://localhost:8120/user/cloudera/example.py`

Comment: Yes it is, previously I set the path as /user/cloudera/example.py and I got the error 'file not found', but now the console just says System.exit(1).

Comment: By "the lib folder", do you mean the lib folder in the local spark python folder?

Answer (score 0):

The error which you are showing is from stdout file of your oozie job. Can you check stderr file once and post your output here. That might have some more clues related to your issue.

You can use oozie web console to trace the oozie job logs.

Comment: The Oozie console just says: WARN org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkActionExecutor: SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[cloudera] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[Hour_Fillter] JOB[0000000-161229183653282-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000000-161229183653282-oozie-oozi-W@spark-cc87] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exit code [1] , with no further details

Comment: Below that you can see a link to console URL. Click on that link and further click on map link, and then task name and then application attempt logs. Inside those logs, you can find 3 kinds of logs syslog/stdout/stderr. You can find your issue in them. Can you try and let me know.

Comment: The stoud output is the one I've posted above, the syslog/stderr just says System exit 1

Answer (score 0):

You should look in spark history (in hue there is a job histoy tab among right top corners options click on that, that will give you history url). Once you have that you can check EXECUTORS tab and click on stdout. You can see the main error there. OOzie logs are always not that readable.

Comment: If I go to Job browser I find a succeded job, and apparently there is no error in the syslog / stdout. But no file is written by Spark to hdfs, if I go to Spark History I don't find anything and the system exit 1 suggests that something went wrong..

Comment: @AlessioRossotti Okay then you should see the hadoop jobhistory(all the retired hadoop applications) and see the logs there